# ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [POST] "/seekers"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I am relatively new to Rails framework. I started doing a POC. I am stuck into strange problem.

My routes.rb has below:

```
resources :seekers, only: [ :index, :show, :create ]
```

My seekers_controller has below code

```
class SeekersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    #byebug
    "some code"
  end
end
```

it was working earlier, i was trying to add another controller resource with same functionality , then realized its not working. Then I reverted back the code just test it, and found the old code is also not working. for every thing it just throws the below error:-

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/seekers"):
```

My rail routes gives me correct as below path:

```
 POST  /seekers(.:format)
            seekers#create
 GET   /seekers/:id(.:format)
```

The Rest Url which i am using as below

```
http://localhost:3000/seekers
```

Don't know what is wrong. everything was working fine earlier. I have tried to changing the routes.rb by multiple way but nothing works.

Appreciate help on this !!!

version details as below:

```
ruby '2.3.3'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.2', '>= 5.2.2.1'
```

Comment: Try restarting your server.

Comment: Have tried multiple times.

Comment: Any idea, Do I need to upgrade the rail version or any gems? This is so frustrating

Comment: Got it work by setup new environment.Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issues in your code!

> seekers_controller.rb

```
class SeekersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    #byebug
    puts "some code"
  end
end
```

> routes.rb

```
resources :seekers, only: [ :index, :show, :create ]
```

Everything should work, make sure that you are making a post request, I recommend for imitation request Postman Program "https://www.getpostman.com/downloads/"